# Django Tastypie ToOneField error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a one-to-one relationship matching a table with property billing records to another with physical addresses, but I keep getting this error. When I search for the error, nothing shows that is relevant to this situation.

I've no idea what "[<PropertyRecord: 242811400004>]" is referencing since it isn't a PIN number and doesn't exist in any tables.

Also, I've been through the data and there are no null values on the pin in either table.

Getting this error:

```
{
error: "The object '[&lt;PropertyRecord: 242811400004&gt;]' has an empty attribute 'pin' and doesn't allow a default or null value."
}
```

Models:

```
class PropertyRecord(models.Model):
    pin = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True, max_length=20)
    date_added = models.DateField(null=True)
    last_chgdte = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=30, null=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("pin", "last_chgdte")
        select_on_save = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pin)


class PropertyAddress(models.Model):
    pin = models.BigIntegerField(db_index=True, max_length=20, unique=True)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    zip_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, null=True)

    class Meta:
        select_on_save = True

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pin)
```

Resources:

```
class PropertyAddressResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = PropertyAddress.objects.all()


class PropertyRecordResource(ModelResource):

    full_address = fields.ToOneField(
        PropertyAddressResource,
        attribute=lambda bundle: PropertyRecord.objects.filter(pin=bundle.obj.pin),
        full=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        queryset = PropertyRecord.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'propertyrecords'
```

Comment: They don't actually have a relationship?

Comment: @Ngenator I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: What exactly are you modeling with a `pin`, it seems like you are trying to model a `ForeignKey` but I'm unsure.

Comment: What I think @Ngenator was saying is that `PropertyAddress` and `PropertyRecord` don't have a relationship in `models.py`.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm trying to match the pin fields in the two tables so that the records in the PropertyAddress model can be included with the PropertyRecord model. I thought that if I used a ForeignKey then it would affect how the records are updated. I want to keep the two models separate from each other and just join them in the api.

Comment: **But what exactly is a `pin`?** is it a "Property Identification Number"? if so, it seems that it *is* a foreign key for the `PropertyRecord`. I think this a problem with your models rather than your API.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You're right, pin is a property id number. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the ORM of Django. My concern with using a foreign key is that it will create enforcement rules when creating and deleting records in the other table. I need to be able to create and delete from either table independently of what happens with the other. I wanted to be able to join the two tables on a matching key (pin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine that joining tables wouldn't be a common need, so it should have a simple solution.

Rather, I was able to get around the issue by using dehydrate, which feels overly complicated but works. +1 to this being a PITA with the extra step to serialize the data.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):

    query_data = PropertyAddress.objects.filter(pin=bundle.obj.pin)
    results = serialize('json', query_data, fields=('street_address', 'city_name', 'zip_code'))
    bundle.data['full_address'] = json.loads(results)
    return bundle
```